# Cross-Origin Request Blocked Issue Between localhost Projects

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cors

I wrote a method for uploading files at client side of a webform asp.net, that uses resumablejs plugin.
The other side I wrote a method on controller of a mvc project, and I actived the cors origin in webconfig of this project like as:

```
<httpProtocol>
 <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"/>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*"/>
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

I used likem this too:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:10811", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class UploadController : ApiController
{}
```

but when I call upload method in firefox I have this error in console:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:5023/Home/UploadFiles. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed)
```

and this error on chrome:

```
Response for preflight does not have HTTP ok status.
```

There are a matter : I tested the client side method with a client of mvc project an it's worked.
What is the problem,Can anyone help me?

Comment: What is the URL of the client? Are they running on different ports or no?

Comment: @NateBarbettini It's `http://localhost:10811/NewUpload.aspx`,yes `port:10811`

Comment: @NateBarbettini and the mvc project is: http://localhost:5023/Home/UploadFile

Comment: Well have you checked what the preflight request _did_ get answered with yet …? As Chrome says, it was _not_ a 200 OK.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to an action filter attribute like this:

```
public class AllowCORSAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Next apply this attribute on your action method or controller class depending upon your requirement. I suggest apply it at action level as it will not make all the action methods cross-orgin accessible:

```
[AllowCORS]
public ActionResult UploadFile()
```

Comment: I do it,params sent to controller,but in controller Request Files Count is 0

Comment: That may be a different issue not related to cross origin restriction

Answer (score -1):

Follow these instructions:

1. Add this section to the web.config of your ASP.NET MVC project inside the `<system.webServer>` section:

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <clear/>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

2. In global.asax on the `Application_BeginRequest` method add some code for preflight response to CORS:

```
if(HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
{  
  //These headers are handling the "pre-flight" OPTIONS call sent by the browser
  HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
    "*");
  HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "OPTIONS, GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE");
  HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Accepts, Content-Type, Origin, Authorization, Api-Version, X-API-KEY, USERGUID");
  HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age",
    "1200");
  HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}         

HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
  "OPTIONS, GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE");

HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
  "Accepts, Content-Type, Origin, Authorization, Api-Version, X-API-KEY, USERGUID");

HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers",
  "Authorization, Api-Version, USERGUID, WWW-Authenticate");
```

Comment: <system.webServer><handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers></system.webServer>

Comment: How does this bit in the comment relate to the answer? If it's part of making the answer work it would help if you can edit it into the answer. If it's not, it would help if you can explain what it's for! :)